Seeking Advice on Battery-Powered MCU Circuit with TPL5111 Timer and MOSFETs
I'm putting together a circuit using a TPL5111 timer to switch power to an MCU like a PICO or ESP32 from a LiPo battery. I've got two MOSFETs - one for turning the power on and one for turning it off. But I'm not super familiar with MOSFETs, so I'm looking for some advice. The datasheet says the MOSFETs can handle 3.3V to trigger and up to 4.2V max. Any tips or tweaks for my setup?
datasheet

